# How to set input value with template driven form in angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using input with one way data binding and want to revert the value 10 if someone puts more than 10.

```
<input type="text" radNumericInput class="form-control" [id]="pageSizeId" [ngModel]="pageSize"
  (ngModelChange)="changePageSize($event)" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}" style="width: 40%;">
```

Comment: Why not just change the input to `type="number"` and set the max value to `max="10"` so they don't even have the option to?

Comment: I cant change type="number" for now.

Comment: I'd be curious why since it looks to be a value of always type number anyway, which means you're doing some non-type safe coalescing between string and number somewhere probably? However just grab the value from the event object on `changePageSize` and `if (e.value) { this.pageSize = 10 }`